# Get path parameters from url in json object

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jackson

I would like to be able to extract values/strings from a url.

I'm trying to **PATCH** something similar to the following json:

**PATCH /companies/{id}**

```
[
  {
    "name" : "some company",
    "address" : "some address",
    "users" : [
       {
           "id" : "/some/path/with/user/1",
           "name": "some name"
       }        
    ] 
  }
];
```

What I would like to be able to do is to extract the "1" from "id" : "/some/path/with/user/1". So basically a function that given a mocked path, the actual path and a path parameter, returns the value of that path parameter, e.g.

```js
"/some/path/with/user/{userId}"
```

```js
"/some/path/with/user/1"
```

```js
"userId"
```

should provide the value "1".

So it's very similar to how jersey is working for the path that is called, e.g.

```java
@PATCH
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/some/path/with/users/{userId}")
public void patchUser(@PathParam("userId") Long userId) {

}
```

where "userId" will get value "1". But I cannot seem to find how jersey has implemented this. Optimally I would like a solution that only uses some packages from jersey.

I'm using java 1.7, jackson 2.1.1, jersey 1.17.1.

Comment: Starting with version 2.3 Jackson supports http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonPointer.html. If you can upgrade the version, then you can JsonNode#at method.